Are there different degrees of CSS !important in WordPress?
I just stumbled across this in a WP site I am customizing:
<h3 style="
    line-height: 1em!important;!importnt;!importqnt;!importqn;!importq;!import;!impor;!impo;!imp;!im;!i;!;
">

Is this a WP-specific thing?
Is it some custom coding that adds multiple layers of !important to their code?

No, this is garbage that will be discarded by the browser.  There's only one !important.

No. There are not different degrees of !important anywhere in css. The closest analogy is at-rule layers which define order of precedence. This is either a mistake or a joke.
